# rout the admin controllers in with HMVC

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc

i have a problem with HMVC

i have admin controller in all my modules like this

```
- modules 

 - users 
     - controllers 
         - admin.php 
         - users.php
     - views
         - admin_create_user.php
         - admin_view_users.php
         - signup.php
         - login.php

 - news
     - controllers
         - admin.php
         - news.php
     - views
         - admin_disply_news.php
         - admin_create_news.php
         - view_news.php
```

---

now when go to users admin the URL  will be link this

- domain.com/users/admin/method .
- domain.com/news/admin/method .

but i need it to be

- **domain.com/admin/users/method**
- **domain.com/admin/news/method**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these codes in "core/MY_Router.php" Inside "MY_Router" Class -
*(class MY_Router extends MX_Router {** ---code goes in here-- **})*

I tried to do this with routing rules and .htaccess but non of them works. Then I edit the MX_Router code and working perfect but one thing to notice you have to create a sub folder on you'r module's controller call '**admin**' and put the controller there to work like this because this way you can use the default routing for modules by calling directly to controller if controller name same as module name.

```
public $module;
private $located = 0;

protected function _set_request($segments = array()){
    $segments = $this->_validate_request($segments);
    // If we don't have any segments left - try the default controller;
    // WARNING: Directories get shifted out of the segments array!
    if (empty($segments))
    {
        $this->_set_default_controller();
        return;
    }

    if ($this->translate_uri_dashes === TRUE)
    {
        $segments[0] = str_replace('-', '_', $segments[0]);
        if (isset($segments[1]))
        {
            $segments[1] = str_replace('-', '_', $segments[1]);
        }
    }

    if($segments[0] == 'admin' && isset($segments[1])){
        if (isset($segments[2])){
            $this->set_method($segments[2]);
            $segments[2] = $segments[2];
        }else{
            $this->set_method('index');
            $segments[2] = 'index';
        }
        $this->directory    = '../modules/'.$segments[1].'/controllers/admin/'; 
        $this->module       = $segments[1];
        $this->class        = $segments[1];

        $segments[1] = $segments[1];


        unset($segments[0]);
        $this->uri->rsegments = $segments;
    }else{
        $segments = $this->locate($segments);

        if($this->located == -1)
        {
            $this->_set_404override_controller();
            return;
        }

        if(empty($segments))
        {
            $this->_set_default_controller();
            return;
        }

        $this->set_class($segments[0]);

        if (isset($segments[1]))
        {
            $this->set_method($segments[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            $segments[1] = 'index';
        }

        array_unshift($segments, NULL);
        unset($segments[0]);
        $this->uri->rsegments = $segments;  
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this to your routes config file:

```
$route['domain.com/admin/users/(:any)'] = 'domain.com/users/admin/method';
$route['domain.com/admin/news/(:any)'] = 'domain.com/news/admin/method';
```

When user type **domain.com/admin/users/method** it will call **user** controller.

[Documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: if i do that then i need to add all modules methods in rout config . and  don't know all modules name. the user can add any module to this script .

Comment: That is the part where **(:any)** jumps in. You can add this at the end of **domain.com/users/admin/method** instead of method: **. $this->uri->segment(3)**.

Comment: you are right, but i don't know all modules name or all controllers in this modules
i need to route it dynamicly

Comment: Can't you add the modul at **uri->segment(4)**, build gather function and from there dynamically route it?

Comment: sorry for letting.. my rout config like this `$route['admin/(:any)']="$1/admin";`It works well, but when the URL include method name like " admin/users/add " Then an error appears "Page Not Found". what should to do now .